# Phusion Passenger cant start Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

ruby 2.1
rails 4.0

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6929703/

Why phusion passenger  cant start the app?

UPD: The log write

> General Ruby interpreter information
>   RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3

but when i write "ruby -v" in console, i get "ruby 2.1.0"

Comment: probably you just need to run "bundle install" in the app root.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` in your app root? Your message is clear: 
`Could not find arel-4.0.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Comment: @hernanvicente i run bundle install and install gem arel, but version of arel is 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your app isn't being run under the correct Ruby interpreter. Use the `passenger_ruby` option to tell Phusion Passenger what Ruby interpreter to use (in your case, I think that's supposed to be Ruby 2.1.0). Consult the documentation for more information about this option.